# separate and create dummy variable columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I have some data in this format:

```
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>    item colors           
#>   <int> <chr>            
#> 1     1 blue             
#> 2     2 blue / pink / red
#> 3     3 pink / white
```

The output I'd like is:

```
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>    item  blue  pink   red white
#>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     1     1     0     0     0
#> 2     2     1     1     1     0
#> 3     3     0     1     0     1
```

In tidyverse, is there an easy way to do this?

If it helps I do have a df of the colors, eg.

```
df_colors
#> # A tibble: 4 × 1
#>   color
#>   <chr>
#> 1 blue 
#> 2 pink 
#> 3 red  
#> 4 white
```

The real example I'm working with has many colors.

Code for data input below:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~item,             ~colors,
     1L,              "blue",
     2L, "blue / pink / red",
     3L,      "pink / white"
  )
df

library(tidyverse)
df_desired <- tibble::tribble(
  ~item, ~blue, ~pink, ~red, ~white,
     1L,    1L,    0L,   0L,     0L,
     2L,    1L,    1L,   1L,     0L,
     3L,    0L,    1L,   0L,     1L
  )

df_desired

df_colors <- tibble::tribble(
    ~color,
    "blue",
   "pink",
    "red",
  "white"
  )
df_colors
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first `separate_rows`  and then `pivot_wider`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  # create row ID:
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  # separate rows on " /":
  separate_rows(colors, sep = ' /') %>%
  # pivot dataframe wider:
  pivot_wider(names_from = colors, values_from = colors, 
              values_fn = function(x) 1, values_fill = 0) %>%
  # deselect obsolete column:
  select(-row)
# A tibble: 3 x 6
   item  blue ` pink` ` red`  pink ` white`
  <int> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1     1       0      0     0        0
2     2     1       1      1     0        0
3     3     0       0      0     1        1
```

Comment: This is so helpful. Just to recap to see if I'm understanding the big picture, it seems like your solution was to (1) use `separate_rows` to create a long file, and then (2) `pivot_wider` to put it back into the original format. I hadn't used `separate_rows` before, and was trying to do it with `separate` and was finding it hard because of the variable number of new columns to create on each row

Comment: Yes `separate_rows` is an incredible useful function that can be used for many scenarios. Please consider accepting if my post helped you.